# Does Cache-Control header work with HTTPS CDN

Tags: https, http-headers, cdn, cache-control, response-headers

How can a CDN cache the content of an HTTPS request using the Cache-Control Header if the headers of the response are all encrypted?

Does the CDN have to be given explicit permission to decrypt the payload and then reencrypt it?

In that case what is the purpose of the `public`/`private` values for the `Cache-Control` header? (In the case where you have to explicitly give the CDN access to the encrypted payloads?

Answer (score 0):

CDN acts like a reverse proxy with cache capability. Every connection is initialized and terminated at CDN POP. If no corresponding items found in the cache, another connection to origin is issued to fetch the data and determine whether to cache it according to the cache policies CDN user defined.

As far as HTTPS concerned, data is decrypted and reencrypted, you need to deploy your SSL certificate to your CDN provider. All the response from origin are visible to CDN.

The value of "Cache-Control" is used as a hint for CDN provider to determine whether they need to cache the item or not.

> Cache-Control: private indicates that all or part of the response
>   message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a
>   shared cache, such as a proxy server.

From [RFC2616 section 14.9.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

CDN providers usually do not cache response with cache-control header set to private but you can override the behavior with your own rules. Almost every CDN provider allows you to customize cache policies.

Comment: It seems here that the important part is what you said here:
> As far as HTTPS concerned, data is decrypted and reencrypted, you need to deploy your SSL certificate to your CDN provider.
That seems to imply there is no such thing as a public CDN, I cannot create a CDN for another website, is that the conclusion here?

The rest of the answer is somewhat unhelpful, because I'm not interested in the expected expected implementation or RFC, but actually the technical implementation.

Comment: You can enable CDN for whatever website (www.example.com), CDN provider will return you a new host name for accessing (www.example.com.azureedge.net), you normally need to do some DNS works such as create a CNAME record point to it to make it transparent to end users. 

For HTTPS, either CDN provider applied the SSL certificate for you or you upload the SSL cerificate to it. In either way, CDN has the ability to read the decrypted response content.

Comment: Conclusion, you need to be the domain owner to enable CDN without changing the end user's accessing point.